# Is a DNF without negations or duplicate terms a disjunction of prime implicants?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

Disclaimer: I am a software engineer with a Bsc. in Informatics, and no signifcant background in Mathematics (sadly).

I have a real life programming problem, which is equivalent to finding all prime implicants of a given boolean expression *which does not contain negations*, and then picking the 'best' one.

My main issue is that I need to keep track of metadata to decide on the 'best' prime implicant based on not-yet-defined metrics. This metadata is not defined for negations, which is why I'd avoid them if possible.

Assume that I can trivially transform my boolean expression into a DNF by repeatedly utilizing associativity (?) to remove all braces. My education is enough for that task. I can then remove all duplicate terms by applying `ABB = AB` and `A+B+B = A+B`.

**Is this negation-free DNF without duplicates a disjunction of prime implicants?**

I cannot think of any cases that would contradict this assumption. However, I'm really rusty in terms of formal proofs and do not trust myself enough to assume that my proof would be correct. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Not necessarily. You may have $AB+AC+ABC$. This DNF is not minimal, $AB$ and $AC$ are prime implicants, while $ABC$ is not. You can use (maybe a modification of) the second step of Quine-McCluskey algorithm to further minimize DNF and obtain prime implicants.

Comment: @SMM you are correct. But I actually don't need the minimal form. I just need all prime implicants so that I can decide on the 'best' one. Thanks for noticing, I will edit the question.